# DownloadManager sends STATUS_FAILED for running download

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I am using Android DownloadManager for download file...but here I am facing bit weird problem,

**STATUS_FAILED** coming for register receiver where download is still running.

any one have idea/suggestion over this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download manager [doesn't work correctly](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18462)

Using [HTTP ETags](http://papaya-backend.net/2013/04/12/why-http-etag-header-may-cause-your-downloading-apps-on-android-failed/) would probably resolve this problem

Comment: can u refer any sample url with eTag..so i can test it.